# Cyclic Reference issue with includes for friend class

Tags: c++, c++14

I have 2 classes: S and R. R has an intance of type S. I want to have R as friend class to have acces to S private methods.
Unfortunately I couldn't build it. Please help me how can I solve this. I tried forward declaration in more ways but it didn't work. I get the following error

> ```
> R.hpp:12:15: error: ‘n1::n2’ has not been declared
>   12 |         R(n1::n2::Sptr s);
> ```

Thanks a lot in advance!.

S.hpp:

```
#ifndef S_H
#define S_H
#include <memory>
    
namespace n1 {
  namespace n2  {
    class S  {   
      friend class c1::R;
      int x;
      inline void print();
    };
    
    using Sptr = std::shared_ptr<S>;
  }
}
    
#endif
```

S.cpp:

```
#include "S.hpp"
#include "R.hpp"
namespace n1 {
  namespace n2 {
    void S::print()
    {
      std::cout<<"S-print\n";
    }
  }
}
```

R.hpp:

```
#ifndef R_H 
#define R_H
#include <memory>
    
namespace n1  {
  namespace c1 {
    class S;
    struct R {
      R(n1::n2::Sptr s);
      void r();
      n1::n2::Sptr s_;
    };
  } 
}
#endif
```

R.cpp:

```
#include "R.hpp"
#include "S.hpp"

namespace n1 {
  namespace c1 {
    R::R(n1::n2::Sptr s):s_(s)
    {}

    void R::r() {
      s_->print();
    }
  }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "R.hpp"
#include "S.hpp"
#include <memory>


int main() {
  auto s = std::make_shared<n1::n2::S>();
  auto r = std::make_shared<n1::c1::R>(s);
  r->r();
  //s.print();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what is c1::R. Where is c1 declared?

Comment: R is in n1::c1 namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the program to work(compile) by using the following modifications in your files:

**S.hpp**

```
#ifndef S_H
#define S_H
#include <memory>
 namespace n1 
 {
     namespace c1 
     {
         class R;
     }
 }
namespace n1 {
  namespace n2  {
    class S  {   
      friend class c1::R;
      int x;
       void print();
    };
    
  //  using Sptr = std::shared_ptr<S>;
  }
}
    
#endif
```

**S.cpp**

```
#include "S.hpp"
//#include "R.hpp"
#include <iostream>
namespace n1 {
  namespace n2 {
    void S::print()
    {
      std::cout<<"S-print\n";
    }
  }
}
```

**R.hpp**

```
#ifndef R_H 
#define R_H
#include <memory>
 namespace n1 
 {
     namespace n2
     {
           class S;
           using Sptr = std::shared_ptr<S>;
     }
 }
namespace n1  {
  namespace c1 {
    class S;
    struct R {
      R(n1::n2::Sptr s);
      void r();
      n1::n2::Sptr s_;
    };
  } 
}
#endif
```

**R.cpp**

```
#include "R.hpp"
#include "S.hpp"

namespace n1 {
  namespace c1 {
    R::R(n1::n2::Sptr s):s_(s)
    {}

    void R::r() {
      s_->print();
    }
  }
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/3ZX9FfmXy).

Answer (score -1):

1. Remove all cross header file includes. (you appear to have done this)
2. Replace missing symbols with forward declarations in the header.
3. Add header file includes removed into cpp files. (you appear to have done this)
4. Redefine the shared_ptr alias when you need it.

Comment: please give a compilable example with classes and namespaces and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @JohnKean I am unclear what in my instructions is not clear.  Which step caused a problem?  After you do every step above in order, your code will compile.  The code you provided does the first step (removed cross header file includes), some of the 2nd, and does not do the 3rd.  If your complaint is "you didn't do the steps for me", then I'm afraid I'll have to live without an accept checkmark.

Comment: for step 3 Add header file includes removed into cpp files
I already have all header file includes in cpp files, what did I miss here ? Thanks

Comment: @JohnKean Oops, sorry 4.  I can't count.  Added numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your help!